# Find array value in another array by $.inArray?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I can find array value exist when `search` key is type `int`. But how can I find array value exist in where key is string e.g.`"a"`, `"b"`?

```
var arr = ["44", "003"];
var search = [];

search[0] = "003";
search["a"] = "88";
search["b"] = "44";

for (var i in arr) {
    console.log($.inArray(arr[i], search));
}
```

### Actual Output

```
-1
0
```

### Expected

```
b
0
```

Comment: Use `for-loop` to iterate `array` not `for-in` loop...

Comment: `search` is not an `array` but `object`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are confusing properties with array indexes.

```
search["b"] = "44";
```

defines the `b` property of  `search` as `'44'`

it does not insert a value into the array.
to insert values into an array at a specified index, you need to specify the index number

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

Reason why you are getting `-1` for `003` is because, when you run `$.inArray`, it will only check index values.

```js
var arr = ["44", "003"];
var search = [];

search[0] = "003";
search["a"] = "88";
search["b"] = "44";

var result = arr.map(function(item) {
  return Object.keys(search).find(function(key) {
    return search[key] == item;
  });
});
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in array functions [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [`.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```
var arr = ["44", "003"];
if(arr.findIndex(e => e === "44") !== -1) {
  //"44" is in the array
}
else {
  //"44" is not in the array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this harder than you need to. This is an O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity.

You need to search the `arr` array and find each value in the `search` object; in order to find the keys.

```js
var arr = ["44", "003"];
var search = {};

search[0] = "003";
search["a"] = "88";
search["b"] = "44";

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var key in search) {
      if (arr[i] === search[key]) {
        console.log(key);
      }
    }
}
```

### jQuery Version

You can always write your own function. The following function is written as a jQuery plugin.

```js
(function($) {
  /**
   * Returns a key in the provided object that is associated with the
   * provided value.
   *
   * @param {object} object
   * @param {object} value
   *
   * @return Returns a key.
   */
  $.inObject = function(object, value) {
    var result = null;
    $.each(search, function(key, val) {
      if (value === val) {
        result = key;
        return false;
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
}(jQuery));

var arr = ["44", "003"];
var search = {
   0  : "003",
  "a" : "88",
  "b" : "44"
};

$.each(arr, function(index, value) {
  console.log($.inObject(search, value));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there any shorter code for that !In php array_key_exist can do with one line .

Comment: @DavidJawphan You could always write a function.

Comment: I think You should convert search object to array then use $.inArray function to reduce complexity @Mr.Polywhirl

Comment: @NeerPriv But converting the WHOLE object over to an array is worse. At least, this way, the search will short-circuit when a matching value is found.

Comment: I think an heuristic approach needs to be introduced (like pre-hashing the key-value pairs) before doing large searches.